# How to serialize a form into an object with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

`$('form').serialize()` will generate something like `a=1&b=2`,but what I want to get is `{a:1,b:2}`.

How to do this?

Further more,is it possible to do this kind of job to arbitrary container like `div`?

Comment: 35 questions / 25% AR is pretty grim.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Serializing to JSON in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery doesn't support this. You'll have to use JSON.stringify, which is supported in some modern browsers, but for support in older browsers, you have to include the [json2 library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) as a `<script>`

You could then have something like:

```
(function ($) {

    jQuery.fn.jsonSerialize = function () {
        var obj = {};
        var form = this[0];

        if (form.tagName !== "FORM") {
            return "";
        }

        $(form.elements).each(function () {
            obj[this.name] = $(this).val();
        });

        return JSON.stringify(obj);
    }

}(jQuery));
```

Then use as follows:

```
var stringified = $('#yourForm').jsonSerialize();
```